# Increase maximum zoom level for a WebTiledLayer in ArcGIS

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wmts

I am using the WebTiledLayer from the Javascript ArcGIS API to render a custom WMTS source. The WMTS I am using has zoom levels going from 18 to 21, however I cannot zoom in further than what appears to be zoom level 19. Does anyone know how to increase the maximum zoom level for a WebTiledLayer?